# Get Primary Key Value After Insert not knowing the Column Name of the Primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to return the primary key value, during an insert, without knowing the Primary Keys Column Name.

I would like to use Output because not all of the Primary Keys in the Database are Integers, but I do not think it is possible to do a subquery for an Output.

```
    CREATE TABLE TestTable
    (
       PkId INT Identity(1,1) NOT NULL,
       Value1 VARCHAR(50) NULL,
       Value2 VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
       CONSTRAINT PkId PRIMARY KEY (PkId)
    )


INSERT INTO TestTable(Value1, Value2)
OUTPUT INSERTED. --Primary Key to find here
Values('Test', 'Test2')
```

I was thinking about using something like this as a subquery, but like I stated before I don't think it is possible to use an output with a subquery

```
SELECT column_name as PRIMARYKEYCOLUMN
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC
INNER JOIN
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS KU
          ON TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' AND
             TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = KU.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND 
             KU.table_name='TestTable'
ORDER BY KU.TABLE_NAME, KU.ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `PkId` is `NOT NULL` so why you're trying to insert `NULL` to it?

Comment: Going to be an Auto Increment sorry I will edit the post to state that

Comment: Okey, so since it's `IDENTITY()` what's the problem with `INSERT INTO TestTable(Value1, Value2)
OUTPUT INSERTED.PkId 
Values('Test', 'Test2')`?

Comment: It seems strange that you know the names of all 'Value' columns but not the name of the 'PK' column. Can't think of a practical reason why or an actual scenario where that would be the *only* unknown column name.

Comment: I will be using this script inside of a c# application and I will be using this for multiple tables so I will not know the Column Name of the Primary Key.

Comment: What details does your C# code receive? An SQL statement?

Comment: C# code gets all of the Column Names for the specific table. What happens is the column names get put into a string split by commas. I then do a string.replace to update the values for the insert statement. I could get the cardinal positions which most likely one will be the primary key every time, but I was trying to see if there was a different way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your query to find the primary key column name but you'd have to execute dynamic SQL to include that column name in the output clause. I've given you an example here but I've also modified it to use standard system views instead of the old information_schema views.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable
(
   PkId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
      CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_TestTable PRIMARY KEY,
   Value1 varchar(50) NULL,
   Value2 varchar(50) NULL 
);
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max) = N'
INSERT INTO TestTable(Value1, Value2)
OUTPUT INSERTED.'
+ QUOTENAME((
SELECT c.[name] 
FROM sys.indexes AS i
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
ON i.object_id = ic.object_id 
AND i.index_id = ic.index_id 
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
ON i.object_id = c.object_id
AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
ON i.object_id = o.object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id 
WHERE i.is_primary_key <> 0
AND o.[name] = N'TestTable'
AND s.[name] = N'dbo'
)) + N' VALUES(''Test'', ''Test2''), (''Test3'', ''Test4'')';

EXEC (@SQL);
GO
```

You can run it in tempdb to see how it works. You'll see it outputs the primary key value each time. Where you will have a problem is if there are multiple columns in your primary key. It can also be done but it's much more complicated code. I'm guessing you'll only have one column anyway so this should be fine.

Hope that helps.